# AVL tree to tuples in C

Tags: c

I have a AVL Tree like:

```
   (6,25)
   /    \
(6,12)  (9,25)
```

I wish to store all element in to a tuples like:

```
array= [(6,12),(6,25),(9,25)]
```

how can I achieve it in C language?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the libraries you are using as well as the code you already have because C doesn't have builtin or standard trees or tuples.

Comment: What have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work? And please take some time to refresh [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: But as a hint, it looks like a normal in-order traversal.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to represent it in breadth-first order, i.e. like a [binary heap](https://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1d/ods-java/node52.html)? That's how you usually represent the tree in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use structures for heterogeneous data like:

```
struct my_eth_tuple
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char s[32];
};
```

Then create the array of tuples:

```
struct my_eth_tuple[3];
```

You can init it also as:

```
struct my_eth_tuple[3] = {{6, 12.0, "tuple 1"},{6, 25, "tuple 2"},{9, 25, "tuple 3"}};
```

If data is homogeneous you can use simple arrays of arrays:

```
typedef int my_hom_tuple[2];
my_hom_tuple[3] = {{6,12},{6,25},{9,25}};
```

To programmatically access the two use standard struct or array usage as in the sample below:

```
struct my_eth_tuple
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char s[32];
};
typedef int my_hom_tuple[2];
struct my_eth_tuple[3];
struct my_hom_tuple[3];

void foo(void)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        my_eth_tuple[i].a = i + 1;
        my_eth_tuple[i].b = (float)i *2.0;
        my_eth_tuple[i].s[0] = '\0';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            my_hom_tuple[i][j] = i + 1;
            my_hom_tuple[i][j] = i * 2;
        }
    }
}
```